# jquery animation to go outside of a div (mask)

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, mask

I am trying to create an animation using jquery by where the text shoots off above or below and the element is then hidden once outside the div

for an example please see here and hover on the 67% section http://swe.se/

anyone any idea where i can find a tutorial on this? I can create the animation, just not display none outside the div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `overflow` to `hidden` in your CSS:

```
#mydiv {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: ha ha oh my word, thats a definate sign for me to go to bed! i missed day one at school of web development! thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to accept and/or upvote if the answer was useful :)!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example of using "outside" events here:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-outside-events-plugin/